# Where is my QML when I run app from Desktop?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have very simple QT Widgets app with QML. It looks like this:

Main ( no changes ):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.11
Item {
    Button {
        text: "Ok"
    }
}
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    widget = new QQuickWidget(this);
    widget->setSource((QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/test.qml"))));
    widget->move(10,10);
    widget->resize(400,400);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

When I run this app from QTCreator, eveything is ok ( I see Button "ok" ). When I run this application from my folder on Desktop I don't see a Button ( my app of course is running ).

My folder on desktop with qmlTest app:
[image]

`test.qml` is in my qrc

Comment: Try opening a cmd located in the executable folder and from there launch your program.

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried and I still don't see a button

Comment: @juga92 do you see any useful output in cmd console? Maybe any errors occurs?

Comment: @eyllanesc used windeployqt.exe :) Thank you for comments!

Comment: @tro I used windeployqt.exe :) Thank you for comments!

Comment: Is this issue occur when you manually copy all qml libs to your binary directory?